# How to log in console javascript array items properties if they have index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to log in console the items of this array if they have index like 0, 1, 2 ?

```
products: Array(1)
  0:
    name: 'abc', 
    size: 'S',
    color: 'white'
  1:
    name: 'abc', 
   size: 'S',
   color: 'white
```

how i access to items:

```
products.forEach(product=> {
   console.log(product.name);
});
```

when i console.log in forEach i get two product item names too. Everything is okey with this.

but when i console.log outside of forEach i can't get the name of two properties but i need to set this names to another object like

```
sendProducts = {
  productName = products.name
}
```

Comment: Use the `.forEach()` method.

Comment: how?  using it in this situation ?

Comment: is `Array` an object where `0`, `1` are keys for the values `name`, `size`, `color` or are they positional indexes. You have mentioned they're indexes, but have posted it similar to what an object is.

Comment: Provide your actual Json instead of example

Comment: @Amitchauhan its that i have some array products{} and inside of this have items but they have numbers when i console log, like an eg. 0,1,2 etc. i want to access this items properties. eg each product item name property then i want to set them to another array

Comment: @czm please See my answer i have tried to explain how actually your program is working

Comment: @Amitchauhan can you check my updated question please?

Comment: @czm see my updated answer is it helping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown it is looking like a Array of Objects 
Your Object is

```
object : {
    name: 'abc', 
    size: 'S',
    color: 'white
}
```

And Array is something like this

```
products: Array(1)
     0:
        name: 'abc', 
        size: 'S',
        color: 'white'
     1:
        name: 'abc', 
        size: 'S',
        color: 'white
```

Lets First understand how we created this Array of object

```js
var products = [];
    var object1= {name:"abc",size:"S",color:"white"};
    products.push(object1);
    var object2= {name:"xyz",size:"M",color:"black"};
    products.push(object2);

    //Now About your actual Question how to access the values of objects
    
    console.log(products[0].name);
    console.log(products[0].size);
    console.log(products[0].color);
    console.log(products[1].name);
    console.log(products[1].size);
    console.log(products[1].color);

   // or you can loop in here  
   var productName = []
   for(let i=0;i<products.length;i++){ 
        productName.push(products[i].name);
   }
   console.log("Product Names Array "+productName);
```

Hope this Explaination Helps

Answer (score 0):

how about `console.log(products.map(p -> p.name)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the name of one specific item, you can use:

```
console.log(products[0].name)
```

If you want to log the name of all items, use the [forEach function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
products.forEach(product => {console.log(product.name)})
```